# Umlauts in DBeaver

Tags: postgresql, encoding, client, dbeaver

I have a Postgres Database set to UTF-8. I am working with DBeaver 3.1.4, and it seems to use a different encoding than UTF-8 (I suppose Latin-1 or something), which leads to

1) wrong display in the views
2) sending queries in the wrong encoding, which makes text search difficult

Where can I set the encoding properly?

[image: screenshot of how DBeaver displays umlaut]

Comment: Set the encoding for DBeaver, for your Postgres Cluster, the one Postgres DB, the query or for your data import? Which one are you after?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter As I suppose DBeaver encoding = query encoding, the DBeaver encoding.

Comment: I don't know DBeaver, but I like to use the Linux tool [iconv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv) to convert encodings.

Comment: this may help: http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=677